# How to format a date android?

Tags: android, android-date

I have a date in  String an I using this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
dataUltima = sdf.format(sdf);
```

to format the date. But this method return the actual date of system. How can I only format the date without change the date.

Obs. I'm getting this date from a server, it come to me yyy-dd-MM and I want it `dd/MM/yyyy`

Comment: what is type of the date that you get from server ?

Comment: I'm getting a String form the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what is your problem.

Try it. Maybe help.

```
String server_format = "2013-01-02";    //server comes format ?
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
try {

    Date date = sdf.parse(server_format);
    System.out.println(date);
    String your_format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(date);
    System.out.println(your_format);    //you want format ?

} catch (ParseException e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString()); //date format error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ty following:

```
try
{
  //create SimpleDateFormat object with source string date format
  SimpleDateFormat sdfSource = new SimpleDateFormat("yyy-dd-MM");

  //parse the original date string(strDate) that you are getting from server into Date object
  Date date = sdfSource.parse(strDate);

  //create SimpleDateFormat object with desired date format
  SimpleDateFormat sdfDestination = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");

  //parse the date into another format
  strDate = sdfDestination.format(date);

  System.out.println("Date is converted");
  System.out.println("Converted date is : " + strDate);

}
catch(ParseException pe)
{
  System.out.println("Parse Exception : " + pe);
}
```

Source: [Convert date string from one format to another format using SimpleDateFormat](http://www.java-examples.com/convert-date-string-one-format-another-format-using-simpledateformat)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm getting a error, nullpointexception  07-16 14:41:10.709: E/AndroidRuntime(28291): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-16 14:41:10.709: E/AndroidRuntime(28291):  at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.parse(SimpleDateFormat.java:1001)
07-16 14:41:10.709: E/AndroidRuntime(28291):  at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:624)
07-16 14:41:10.709: E/AndroidRuntime(28291):  at com.example.Tappa.SegundaTelaActivity.onCreate(SegundaTelaActivity.java:171)

Comment: Which is `171` line in your activity? Also make sure that `strDate` is not null before you pass it into this for converting date. Are you logging the date which comes from your server. Is it non-null?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String date = "2011-11-12 11:11:11"; //Fill with sample date received from server
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss");
Date testDate = null;
try {
    testDate = sdf.parse(date);
}catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");
String dataUltima = formatter.format(testDate);
System.out.println("Date is "+dataUltima );
```

Comment: I'm getting a error to      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
07-16 14:50:00.239: E/AndroidRuntime(29237):  at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:365)
07-16 14:50:00.239: E/AndroidRuntime(29237):  at java.text.Format.format(Format.java:93)

Comment: What is your server date coming as? This works for me if the date that you get from your server is of the form "yyy-dd-MM" only with any time component . Is this how it comes ? If not it will throw an error

Comment: It comes for me as a String: "yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss" and I want it dd/MM/yyy HH:mm

Comment: Oh in your question you said just yyy-dd-mm. Then you have to format it as is. edited

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    Date newDate = new Date();

    // Print the date with the server format
    SimpleDateFormat sdfServer = new SimpleDateFormat("yyy-dd-MM ");
    System.out.println("Server date " + sdfServer.format(newDate));

    // Create a new formatter to get the date in the format you want
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
    String dataUltima = sdf.format(newDate);
    System.out.println("System date " + dataUltima);
```