# Android get only time from iso-8601

Tags: java, android

I am making an API call to server when logging in user. API call returns JSON format data with field:

time_logged_in - time in iso-8601 format, for example, 2013-08-19T14:29Z

But in my TextView I would like only to display the time when user logged in, for example, 14:29.

Can anyone help and tell me how could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to convert from one format to another. Then you can extra the relevant part from that. One way is following:

```
String server_format = "2013-08-19T14:29Z";    //server comes format ?
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZ");
try {

    Date date = sdf.parse(server_format);
    System.out.println(date);
    String your_format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").format(date);
    String [] splitted = your_format.split(" ");
    System.out.println(splitted[1]);    //The second part of the splitted string, i.e time
    // Now you can set the TextView here
    

} catch (ParseException e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString()); //date format error
}
```

P.S I haven't tested this code. Hope you get the concept. See [How to format a date android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17683097/how-to-format-a-date-android/17683236#17683236) for more.

Another way is to use `.split()` using `T` as delimiter. Then just remove the `Z` part using answers given on [Remove all occurrences of char from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576352/java-remove-all-occurances-of-char-from-string) and show the result it in `TextView`.

Third way can be to replace `T` and `Z` with `" "` ( space ) using `.replace` function. Then using `.split()` you can just split the string using `" "` as delimiter. The second element of the array returned will give time to you.

Comment: I am getting error:   java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2013-08-29T05:23Z"

Comment: Try few things: `1)` Remove the single quote around `T`. i.e Do `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmZ");` now. If that does not work, try second and third way of doing it.

Comment: Now I got the runtime exception. Will try the other two ways

Comment: Its not working because you don't have single quotes around `T` in your input date, which usually is there. Nevertheless the other two ways are easier I guess.

Comment: I used the second way, using "T" as delimiter and it works! Thank you for that. But I have one more question. The iso-8601 is given in UTS time zone, but how can I modify the time to show it correct at my time zone. For example, my clock now shows 11.23 but I am getting the time 07:23. Any suggestions for that?

Comment: Glad it solved your issue. For your other question see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088778/converting-utc-dates-to-other-timezones

Comment: So instead of single quotes, double quotes didn't give error, right?

Comment: This is how I set the simple date format:   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'") . Single quotes around Z also

Comment: I am now trying to get the users time zone. What am I doing wrong?

`TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'");
    sdf.setTimeZone(tz);
    String [] splitted = null;
    try {
     Date date = sdf.parse(ticket.getEstimatedTimeOfService());
     String format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").format(date);
     splitted = format.split(" ");
    } catch (Exception e) {
     Log.d("Errorrr", String.valueOf(e));
    }`

Comment: Better post a new question with that issue :). Also mention the error that you are getting. Give me a link here. That'll make it easier. Also if the answer helped you feel free to accept the answer.

Comment: @John What is the issue that you are facing with the time zone changing ?